# What is react-virtualized is all about? How its different from normal react.js?

Tags: react-virtualized

how react-virtualized in different than normal reactJs. Can anyone please explain me with an example ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Author of react-virtualized here. I think you might find the slides from a recent presentation I made about the library helpful. I suggest starting here and stepping through the slides (by pressing the right arrow key): https://bvaughn.github.io/forward-js-2017/#/10/0

I think this talk will be posted to the Forward JS YouTube channel soon but as of now, only the slides are available.

In short, react-virtualized helps improve the performance of your React application by limiting the number of calls to render as well as the number of DOM elements created and added to the page.

Edit: [Link to the Forward JS talk](https://youtu.be/t4tuhg7b50I)

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the reply. I am facing an issue with react-virtualised. Always getting below error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined. But the same code is working for react-virtualized-infinite-scroll. Any Pointer ?

Comment: This is because `react-virtualized-infinite-scroll` has a dependency on react `>=0.14.0` but `react-virtualized` (as of version 9) depends on react `15.3.0` or newer in order to extend `PureComponent`. When you install, NPM warns you about a dependency mismatch. PS. You should mark this answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Thanks Brian. Got the issue.